# VHD file size is less than the size of its contents

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, vhd, dynamic-disk, vhdx

I have made a dynamic VHD file with Windows Disk Management, and populated it by copying a folder on my main disk into the VHD volume.

When I view the properties of the mounted virtual disk in Explorer, or when I view the combined properties of all files and folders on the disk, the total size occupied is listed as 150GB.
However, the size of the VHD file itself is only 130GB.

I have not enabled NTFS compression on the VHD's volume. I have heard of NTFS deduplication, however this seems to be a feature that is not enabled by default and is only available on Windows Server editions.

Using a file comparison program, the files on the VHD volume are identical to the source files on my main disk that I copied to the VHD (and the source files are also stated as taking up 150GB), so the files do not seem to be only partially copied or corrupted.

Does anyone know of an explanation of what is being done by the Windows VHD driver or the NTFS file system that is allowing 150GB of files to be fit inside a 130GB VHD file without using compression or deduplication?

Comment: "View the combined properties of all files and folders on the disk," - This explains the behavior you witness.  Before I explain the behavior by submitting an answer, I need to understand, the size of the partition within the Virtual Machine itself.

Comment: @Ramhound The VHD is a dynamic VHD and the NTFS volume size is set to 256GB. Out of these 256GB it is stated that 150GB is used when checking the volume itself (when VHD is mounted).

Comment: So the partition of the system disk within the VM is 256 GB and the dynamic VHDD is 130 GB? This while the VM is turned on or off?

Comment: I am using VHD files as a data holding file format, not for a virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the way that you copied the files, it's possible that you
have large files that contain large sections that have only zero bytes.

This will cause these files to become
[Sparse Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-files),
where these stretches of zeroes are compressed and not allocated
any disk space. However, Windows will still know the real size of the files.

For any given file, you may right-click it in Explorer and select
"Properties" to see the difference between "Size" and "Size on disk".
For a sparse file the first will be much larger than the second.
(There might be slight differences because the last sector in the
file may end with an unallocated space that is not counted
in Size.)

Comment: The "Size" of the files within the VHD volume is 149GB and 150GB "Size on disk". The mounted volume states that 150GB of the 256GB maximum (the VHD is dynamic) is used. The size of the actual VHD file is 130GB for both "Size" and "Size on disk"

Comment: If there is no error in your calculations, this means that the "Size on disk" is wrongly calculated somewhere. Do `chkdsk` in the host and VM, just to be sure that there is no problem.

Comment: chkdsk returns no problems for both discs, however I think you are probably correct that there must be some NTFS size metadata corruption for some of the files which is causing this discrepancy. Do you know of any tools that can verify this sort of thing? chkdsk does not seem to be thorough enough.

Comment: Chkdsk is the only tool. You could verify that that the copy was correct by some compare tool between host and guest. If the compare result is OK, then my only theory is that the "Size on disk" is incorrect for sparse files.